# swing application and osgi felix

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

I've created a very simple bundle:

```
public class Main implements BundleActivator, ServiceListener{

public void start(BundleContext bc) throws Exception {

    bc.addServiceListener(this);

    //trivial system out
    System.out.println("started");

    //output to file
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("test.txt");
    fw.write("it has worked");
    fw.close();

    //opening of a frame
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    JLabel l = new JLabel("test");
    f.add(l);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.pack();

}

(other methods with empty body)
```

I've edited the manifest file:

```
Bundle-Name: Service listener example
Bundle-Description: A bundle that displays messages at startup and whe service events occur
Bundle-Vendor: Apache Felix
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-Activator: tosgi01.Main
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework
```

I've jar'ed up all this stuff, launched felix and:
start file:testosgi.jar

It doesn't gives an error, but doesn't work too.
Is there a way to get some detailed information on what's going on?

Comment: I think this link [http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/osgi-modularizing-your-application.html](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/osgi-modularizing-your-application.html) provide you a better solution for your need.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure but I think you must specify the Bundle-SymbolicName in your manifest.
You also have to import the javax.swing package (etc..). Those packages are by default not available.

We have a lot of output in the console in our application so it is o overlook a message. For me it often helps to stop and start he bundle in question.

You should also give the console/shell a try it offers tools to diagnose problems with bundles.

Comment: +1 This is correct the bundle won't be registered without a SymbolicName and as @chilicat.dev states; use the console commands to give you a better handle on what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot directly help you, but in case you missed it: the NetBeans Platform (Swing based RCP) comes with OSGi and Apache Felix support:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/OSGiAndNetBeans

Comment: It is very intresting, but my application should just be a container around a few pluggable modules. Not dockable windows, no toolbars, probably no desktop pane.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the many debugging options for such problems, the Felix Web Console [1] is my favorite.

Check that your bundle is active, and if not look at the error messages on the console's bundle details page. If you have doubts about the Swing stuff you can also remove it at first, and start by checking that your bundle activator is indeed called.

[1] http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-web-console.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have missed "Bundle-SymbolicName" tag in your manifest, which is mandatory.

Second, Felix has a console bundle called [Gogo](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-gogo.html), which can help you to understand is your bundle started or not. Just install this bundle and write into console

```
lb
```

and you will the the list of installed bundles. Find your bundle and if it has "active" state, everything is fine. If not, write

`start <your_bundle_number>`

and see the log.

If it doesn't help, find in file conf/config.properties line `felix.log.level=1` and change it to `felix.log.level=4`. You will see in log whole process of starting bundle.